# Best way to handle Activity Stack on Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a particular scenario and NOT ale to find solution.
I have my activity stack as A->B->C->D. From D when use presses done, I want to start activity A and clear stack which I achieved with starting activity A with the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.
Now comes the problem:
My activity B can also be started from an intent that other applications can fire.In this case once user is at Activity D and I start activity A with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, Activity D still remains in the back stack as Activity A was NOT there in the stack.
Can someone point out how to handle this scenario?

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Activity D or Activity B remains in stack?

Comment: After using clear top and starting the activity use finish(); too.. that will solve your problem.

Comment: @JaiKumar But in that case B and C would remain in the backstack, so that wont solve this

Comment: @agomov so if my application is started from and intent to B, My back stack would be B->C->D. After Pressing Done on D, i Want stack to have only A

Comment: @manan No. If u use clear_top the previous activities will get cleared from the stack. only the activity that initiates clear top remains in the stack that too if use finish(); the entire stack will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Why not invoke Activity A with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and then finish() activity D ?

Comment: This is same as jaiKumar solution in the comments.But in that case B and C would remain in the backstack, so that wont solve this

Comment: B and C wont be in the stack as we do ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. As the doc says "If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent."

Comment: Or you can use "FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK" which will clear the complete stack.

Comment: Note "If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task". In my case A is NOt in current task, The stack is B->C->D and what i want is to start A and clear everything, there will be nothing on top of A in this case so CLEAR_TOP will do nothing

Comment: Use "FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK". Initially you had posted A->B->C-D. This gave an impression, that A was launched earlier.